Why does a bubble created in the body of a liquid pop when it rises to the surface?
Suppose you have a glass of water and you blow bubbles in the water using a straw. The bubbles pop when they rise to the surface of water. Why does this happen? Does the surface tension of water play a role in this?

The high surface tension of pure water means that thin films of it are unstable, and will get thinner until a hole develops and lets the air out.

Also wouldn't pressure play a major role in the process? If the bubbles are created inside the body of water, it means they are created under conditions of pressure that are higher than those of the atmosphere, and therefore when they reach the surface, the pressure of the air inside outweighs the atmospheric pressure and the bubble pops. Is my reasoning correct?

No, when you blow a bubble into water, the bubble expands so that the interior pressure is equal to the pressure outside.

Oh of course! I hadn't considered the expansion!
